# SystemWideListXml() not returning complete results

Tags: core-service

I am using the below code for getting the List of publications :

```
PublicationsFilterData filter = new PublicationsFilterData() { 
                                            BaseColumns =ListBaseColumns.IdAndTitle };

var pubs = CoreServiceClient.coreService.GetSystemWideList(filter);
```

But the results returned are incomplete. Out of around 500 publications, only 2 publications are returned.

Can anyone Please help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GetList for publications has postProcessing, where only publications on which user has Rights.PublicationAccess return to user.
So there can be only one explanation - your user doesn't have rights to view content of the other publications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer the issue is resolved now. The user should be a Administrator or should have access on all the publications so as to get the complete list of publications.

Comment: Nearly all of the CM-side APIs will act as the user making the API call. "Where am I" is the first gotcha. "Who am I" is the second. :-)

Answer (score 7):

The code seems fine.

Verify that the user with which you are authenticating the Core Service call have permission on all of these publications.

Also, it would be good if you can check your windows logs for potential errors and warning and share them here.